# how to use Wi-Fi Coverage Extend Feature in Android 6.0

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, developer-options

I have Android 6.0 phone and i don't have Wi-Fi Coverage Extend Feature on developer options ,So i want to know if i can use this feature in my Android 6.0 phone.

Thank you

Comment: Where did you see that feature?

Comment: @IrfanLatif looks like [a feature of OnePlus/OxygenOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/9yl9mh/what_is_wifi_coverage_extend_feature/). // OP: could you mention your device model?

Comment: Since this question is not really about *using the existing Wi-Fi Coverage Extend feature* (which is only available on a few manufacturers) but how to enable it on devices that don't have this setting, it's closed as a dupe of using the hotspot as a Wi-Fi repeater since that's what the feature actually does (ref: [XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/coverage-extend-feature.3844013/))